# Footer div is not being pushed down

Tags: html, footer, expand

I have a div for the header, two divs in the middle and one div as the footer. The middle divs are set for float:left and float:right. When the middle divs grow vertically, I want the footer div to push down on the page. It currently only works in IE. On all other browsers, the footer div remains in the same spot and the other divs just overlap the footer. What am I doing incorrectly?

Also, all of these divs are wrapped in a parent div.

Thanks

Comment: A view of the code will be helpful.

Comment: Add `clear: both` to the footer, and `overflow: hidden` for the two middle divs

Answer (score 2):

Have you cleared float before the footer div?

If not, put a div before the footer div with the style

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: clear:both worked. I had it in the class for the stylesheet but for some reason that did not work. It worked when I put it on the div itself.

Thanks